# requiring module scrollview which threw an exception react-native

Tags: react-native

[image]

I'm having an error on a screen in React Native. I have no idea what is going on and it happens as soon as I click a button. The app actually freezes on this screen.

Answer (score 0):

Seemed to be some transient issue. I commented out some things, then uncommented them and it worked. No code was changed. What a load of horseshit.